# Script of memory threshold auto email notification

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have created the script which use to send email notification when server memory breach the threshold limits. Script works fine, but the issue is sometimes i am receiving mail alerts for lower threshold memory also.
Please let me know why and any updates required in script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell script to monitor or watch the high Mem-load
# It will send an email to $ADMIN, if the (memroy load is in %) percentage
# of Mem-load is >= 80%
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
LOAD=80.00
CAT=/bin/cat
MAILFILE=/tmp/mailviews
MAILER=/bin/mail
mailto="skrishna1@xxx.com"
MEM_LOAD=`free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf("Current Memory Utilization is : %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'`
if [[ $MEM_LOAD > $LOAD ]];
then
PROC=`ps -eo pcpu,pid -o comm= | sort -k1 -n -r | head -1`
echo "Please check your processess on ${HOSTNAME} the value of cpu load is $CPU_LOAD % & $PROC" > $MAILFILE
echo "$(ps axo %mem,pid,euser,cmd | sort -nr | head -n 10)" > $MAILFILE
$CAT $MAILFILE | $MAILER -s "Memory Utilization is High > 80%, $MEM_LOAD % on ${HOSTNAME}" $mailto
fi
```

Comment: General note: please avoid using CAPITALIZED variable names in shell scripts. The convention is to use ALLCAPS for system variables such as `HOSTNAME` (which already exists, there's no reason to do `HOSTNAME=$(hostname)`, `$HOSTNAME` will already be defined). When you have your own variables use ALLCAPS as well, you can end up with some really strange problems because you will be setting system variables by mistake.

Comment: Also, what's `CPU_LOAD`? You aren't actually setting it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Make those lines:

```
MEM_LOAD=`free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf("Current Memory Utilization is : %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'`
if [[ $MEM_LOAD > $LOAD ]];
```

to be

```
MEM_LOAD=`free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf("Current Memory Utilization is : %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'`
MEM_L=`free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {print int($3/$2*100)}'`
if [ $MEM_L -gt $LOAD ];
```

You compare string with number. Or you can skip one `awk:

```
MEM_L=`free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {print int($3/$2*100)}'`
MEM_LOAD=`echo "Current Memory Utilization is: "${MEM_L} "%"`
if [ $MEM_L -gt $LOAD ];
```

And use integer for LOAD variable

```
LOAD=80
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your script, with a few improvements:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Shell script to monitor or watch the high Mem-load
# It will send an email to $ADMIN, if the (memroy load is in %) percentage
# of Mem-load is >= 80%

# you don't need this, $HOSTNAME is a system variable and
## already set.
#HOSTNAME=`hostname`

#Use lowercase variable names to avoid name collision with system variables. 
load=80
mailer=/bin/mail
mailto="skrishna1@xxx.com"

## You can't use decimals in a shell arithmetic comparison, but you can use awk
## to do the test for you instead.
if free -t | awk -vm="$load" 'NR == 2 { if($3/$2*100 > m){exit 0}else{exit 1}}'; then
  ## You weren't setting your "$CPU_LOAD" anywhere. It looks like you want the % use,
  ## so I am setting it here. Also note how I'm using $() instead of backticks.
  ## There's nothing wrong with backticks, but the $() is cleaner, easier to nest
  ## and generally preferred.
  cores=$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
  cpuPerc=$(ps -eo pcpu= | awk -vcores=$cores '{k+=$1}END{printf "%.2f", k/cores}')
  ## Get the more actual value for reporting
  memPerc=$(free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf("%.2f%"), $3/$2*100}')

  ## Avoid using a temp file
  message=$(cat <<EoF
Please check your processess on $HOSTNAME the value of cpu load is $cpuPerc% & Current Memory Utilization is: %$memPerc.
$(ps axo %mem,pid,euser,cmd | sort -nr | head -n 10)
EoF
         )
  printf '%s\n' "$message" | 
    "$mailer" -s "Memory Utilization is High > $load%, $memPerc % on $HOSTNAME" \
     "$mailto"
fi
```